How can the MSB8040 error be fixed when building VS Code from source?
I was trying to install VS Code from its repository (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode). However, when running "yarn" in the VSCode directory, the following error appears:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(504,5): error MSB8040: Spectre-mitigated libraries are required for this project. Install them from the Visual Studio installer (Individual components tab) for any toolsets and architectures being used. Learn more: https://aka.ms/Ofhn4c [C:\Users\parsonjc\vscode\node_modules\@vscode\policy-watcher\build\vscode-policy-watcher.vcxproj]

However, I have already installed the following individual components:

MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 Spectre-mitigated libs (Latest)
C++ ATL for latest v142 build tools with Spectre Mitigations (x86 & x64)
C++ MFC for latest v142 build tools with Spectre Mitigations (x86 & x64)

I tried running "yarn" in the vscode directory inside an Adminstrator Command Prompt, but it doesn't work.
I am running this on an x64-based processor on Windows 10.
